# Insert PHP code In WordPress Page and Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know the *visitor* country using PHP and display it in on a WordPress Page. But when I add PHP code to a WordPress page or post it gives me an error.

How can we add PHP code on WordPress pages and posts?

```
<?PHP
    try
    {
        function visitor_country()
        {
            $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $result  = "Unknown";
            if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            {
                $ip = $client;
            }
            elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            {
                $ip = $forward;
            }
            else
            {
                $ip = $remote;
            }

            $ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));

            if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
            {
                $result = array('ip' => $ip,
                                'continentCode' => $ip_data->geoplugin_continentCode,
                                'countryCode' => $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode,
                                'countryName' => $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName,
                                );
            }
            return $result;
        }


        $visitor_details = visitor_country(); // Output Country name [Ex: United States]
        $country = $visitor_details['countryName'];
```

Comment: What error does this give you?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

WordPress does not execute PHP in post/page content by default unless it has a shortcode.

The quickest and easiest way to do this is to use a plugin that allows you to run PHP embedded in post content.

There are two other "quick and easy" ways to accomplish it without a plugin:

- **Make it a shortcode** (put it in `functions.php` and have it echo the country name) which is very easy - see here: [Shortcode API at WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)
- **Put it in a template file** - make a custom template for that page based on your default page template and add the PHP into the template file rather than the post content: [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template)

Comment: I am using custom theme,I created one page from admin back-end and I want to use different header structure(top part of page) for this page only. I can't use template file here. I want to do using back-end page only. I put one short code in that set one variable & checked in header.php is that value getting or not? so that depending on that value I will display header.php part which I want for this page.  but this variable's value is getting blank. Please, tell me solution

Comment: Downvoted for giving links instead of providing a solution. When those pages move, this answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 16):

You can't use PHP in the WordPress back-end Page editor. Maybe with a plugin you can, but not out of the box.

The easiest solution for this is creating a shortcode. Then you can use something like this

```
function input_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<input name="' . $name . '" id="' . $name . '" value="' . (isset($_GET\['from'\]) && $_GET\['from'\] ? $_GET\['from'\] : '') . '" type="' . $type . '" />';
}
add_shortcode( 'input', 'input_func' );
```

See the [Shortcode_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Answer (score 14):

**Description**:

there are 3 steps to run PHP code inside post or page.

1. In `functions.php` file (in your theme) add new function
2. In `functions.php` file (in your theme) register new shortcode which call your function:

```
add_shortcode( 'SHORCODE_NAME', 'FUNCTION_NAME' );
```

3. use your new shortcode

**Example #1**: just display text.

In functions:

```
function simple_function_1() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode1', 'simple_function_1' );
```

In post/page:

```
[own_shortcode1]
```

Effect:

```
Hello World!
```

**Example #2**: use for loop.

In functions:

```
function simple_function_2() {
    $output = "";
    
    for ($number = 1; $number < 10; $number++) {    
        // Append numbers to the string
        $output .= "$number<br>";
    } 
    
    return "$output";
}

add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode2', 'simple_function_2' );
```

In post/page:

```
[own_shortcode2]
```

Effect:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Example #3**: use shortcode with arguments

In functions:

```
function simple_function_3($name) {
    return "Hello $name";
}

add_shortcode( 'own_shortcode3', 'simple_function_3' );
```

In post/page:

```
[own_shortcode3 name="John"]
```

Effect:

```
Hello John
```

**Example #3** - without passing arguments

In post/page:

```
[own_shortcode3]
```

Effect:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

When I was trying to accomplish something very similar, I ended up doing something along these lines:

wp-content/themes/resources/functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'my_php_function');
function my_php_function() {
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page-with-custom-php') !== false) {
        // add desired php code here
    }
}
```