# executing php on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website, and i wanna execute my php code on my wordpress. my php code does web crawling. Can anyone guide me on how to run my code on wordpress, i've tried using plugins such as insert php, global content blocker and exec-php, but i keep on getting errors.

[image: error message on my wordpress]

```
  <?php

$to_crawl ="http://eklas.msu.edu.my.com";
$c = array();

function get_links($url) {
global $c;
$input = @file_get_contents($url);
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU",$input,$matches);
$base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$l = $matches[2];

foreach($l as $link){

    if (strpos($link, "#")){
        $link = substr($link, 0, strpos($link, "#"));   
    }

    if (substr($link,0,1) == ".") {
        $link = substr($link, 1);
    }

    if (substr($link, 0, 7)== "http://"){
            $link = $link;
        }else if (substr($link, 0, 8)== "https://"){
            $link = $link;
        }else if (substr($link, 0, 2)== "//"){
            $link = substr($link, 2);
        }else if (substr($link, 0, 1)== "#"){
            $link = $url;
        }else if (substr($link, 0, 7)== "mailto:"){
            $link = "[".$link."]";
        } else{
            if (substr($link, 0, 1) != "/") {
                $link = $base_url."/".$link;
            } else {
                $link = $base_url.$link;
            }
        }

        if (substr($link, 0, 7) != "http://" && substr($link, 0, 8) != "https://" && substr($link, 0, 1) != "["){
            if (substr($url, 0, 8) == "https://") {
                $link = "https://".$link;
            }else {
                $link = "http://".$link;
            }
        }


        //echo $link."<br />";
        if (!in_array($link, $c)){
            array_push($c, $link);
        }
    }   
}

get_links($to_crawl);

foreach ($c as $page){
//get_links($page);
echo $page."<br />";
}

//foreach ($c as $page){
```

//   echo $page."
";
   //}
   ?>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post

Comment: consider using this method instead

Comment: The error in the image suggests that you have to rename the function get_links() to something else. It conflicts with another function with the same name.

Comment: thanks guys, very help full tips