# Replace localhost url in the wordpress editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress.
I am converting html site to wordpress site and have added webpage content in the wordpress text editor. Everything is fine, but i have a link in that webpage which redirects to home page,
i.e anchor tag with reference to index.html. So after adding that page to wordpress in text editor, i have changed it to
"http://localhost/sitename/" which links to home page.

My question is, how to remove localhost and yet link it to homepage. I tried php home_url(); inside anchor tag but didn't work.

I am attaching screenshot
[image]

Comment: `<a href="/">Home</a>`?

Comment: that will open the directory, i want to link it to homepage(index.html) without using localhost in url

Comment: Then `/sitename/index.html`, or just `/sitename/`, if you have the auto-index feature :) You don't have to write `http://localhost` explicitly (no need in absolute URLs on your own site). Well, there is `get_home_url()` function. In a PHP script you can do something like `<a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">Home</a>`

Comment: I got it. And if i change my site's name, i need to change /sitename/index.html in all pages. Is there anything like "/home_page_url/index.html" so that i don't need to change in all pages in case if i change site's name in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`home_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) PHP function:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Home</a>
```

You may need to install a widget/plugin to support PHP in WordPress pages. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post) answer.

Comment: it made the whole anchor tag disappear!

Comment: @Nag, is it a PHP script, or static HTML? It can't just disappear. There should be something in the source of the page. If there is nothing, then something should be written to the server logs (if it is a PHP script, again).

Comment: it's a static html page

Comment: i have attached screenshot..hope it's more clear now

Comment: ...so only way is, add sitename to the url since its just html page in the. Alright, Thanks for the help

Comment: @Nag, you probably need a widget/plugin to support PHP. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post) answer.

Comment: yeah..i got it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
get_site_url( int $blog_id = null, string $path = '', string $scheme = null )
```

Retrieves the URL for a given site where WordPress application files (e.g. wp-blog-header.php or the wp-admin/ folder) are accessible.

```
get_home_url( int $blog_id = null, string $path = '', string|null $scheme = null )
```

Retrieves the URL for a given site where the front end is accessible.

In your case you can use

```
<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help if I am understanding your question:

1. Login to WordPress admin dashboard
2. Click on Settings >> General
3. Fill in your WordPress Address and Site Address and click Save.

Comment: my question is very simple,i want to link that webpage to homepage(i.e index.html) without using localhost in url

Comment: If you set the URLs in the settings page and then use the home_url() it will use the point to your home page e.g. http://yourdomainname.com

Comment: <a href="/silverspring/">Home</a>

Comment: i think there's no solution except giving the sitename

Comment: Alryt, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

use the broken link checker plugin. which will scan all your links and return to you all the links that are not part of your site()_url then you can just edit the urls, find plugin [here](https://en-za.wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/)  or you may go to you php myAdmin and run the following query

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/silverspring/', 'www.yourlivesite.com/');
```

wp_ will depend of what you have given your tables prefix.