# How to add Full Php Code from page template php to shortcode wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this php code that is in one of my page templates events-template.php
I want to show it in on my homepage but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas on how this can be implemented.
Thanks!

```
<?php 
JAMSESSION_SWP_put_the_title("div", get_the_title(), "post_title", "");

while (have_posts()) 
{
    the_post();

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 100,
        'posts_per_page'   => 100,
        'offset'           => 0,
        'category'         => '',
        'orderby'          => array('event_date' => 'DESC', 'event_time' => 'DESC'),
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => 'event_date',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'js_events',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => '',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'event_date' => array(
               'key' => 'event_date'
            ),
            'event_time' => array(
               'key' => 'event_time'
            )               
        ),          
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args);

    echo '<div id="postmeta_custom">';
    echo ' <span class="post_cat">';  JAMSESSION_SWP_list_custom_terms_with_links('event_category', '', 'all'); echo "</span>";
    echo '</div>';

    /*events_content using $myposts var*/
    if ('masonry' == JAMSESSION_SWP_get_events_view()) {
        require_once(get_template_directory().'/views/events_content_masonry.php');
    } else {
        require_once(get_template_directory().'/views/events_content_list.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert PHP code In Wordpress Page and Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post)

Comment: Probably you can find its answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Looking at the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png), a WordPress homepage could be using either front-page.php or home.php.

Comment: So I'm trying to add it to my page text editor with a shortcode, don't really want to add it directly to my front-page.php etc. because I wont be able to position it in the spot I would like it to show.

Comment: You probably want to read up on creating custom shortcodes then https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API