# Wordpress Text Widget replaces php tags with html comment tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, text, tinymce, comments

I am attempting to add some php to a page on my wordpress site in the code editor part of my tiny mce editor. However, whenever type something like:

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

and then save the article, when I next go to edit the article it replaces my php tags with a html comment:

```
<!--?php echo "Hello World"; ?-->
```

Would be very grateful if anyone knows what is going on here and why WordPress is doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert PHP code In Wordpress Page and Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post)

Answer (score 1):

To use PHP code in your content editor, you will either need to install a plugin that allows you to do this, or create a shortcode.

To create a shortcode in functions.php:

```
<?php
function hello_shortcode() {
    echo 'Hello world!';
}
add_shortcode('hello', 'hello_shortcode');
?>
```

Then in the content editor, put:

```
[hello]
```

Hope this helps.