# Wordpress Execute PHP in Post 2020

Tags: php, wordpress

In short, the php in this code will not render for me, when used in a Wordpress Post:

`<div class="post" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>)"></div>`

From what I've gathered, this would work formerly, but executing php in a post is now blocked by Wordpress, is this correct ?

I have also tried embedding the php into a shortcode:

`<div class="post" style="background-image: url([xyz-ips snippet="PostThumbURL"])"></div>`

but this resulted in the same outcome. I do wonder if this may be a conflict between the double-quotes in the shortcode and those in the html tag perhaps ? Not sure if there is a way to escape these ?

Hopefully there is a modern method to achieve this in 2020 ?

Many thanks all.

Comment: This might help you with your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896146/insert-php-code-in-wordpress-page-and-post

Comment: Yeah thanks for this @HassanAzzam - for some reason I have not been able to get shortcodes to execute either. Actually, now that I think about it - perhaps my issue is related to a conflict between the shortcode double-quotes and the ones in the html tag ?

Comment: ya it might be, try using single-quotes for the short code see if it fix the issue

Comment: _“From what I've gathered, this would work formerly”_ - no, not without any additional plugins to facilitate that. WordPress itself does not execute PHP code entered via the editor. (And that is not a recent change or anything.)